# Flutter/Dart - Edit Page in PageView, then Refresh and Scroll back to Same Place?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview, flutter-routes

Currently, I can submit edits to a single page in a `PageView` and then either `Navigator.push` to a newly created single edited page or `Navigator.pop` back to the original `Pageview` containing the unedited page.

But I'd prefer to pop back to the the same place in an updated/refreshed Pageview. I was thinking I could do this on the original PageView page:

```
       Navigator.pushReplacement(context,new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (BuildContext context) => EditPage()),);
```

But after editing, how can I pop back to a refreshed PageView which is scrolled to the now updated original page? Or is there a better way? Someone mentioned keys, but I've not yet learned to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The question deals with the concept of Reactive App-State. The correct way to handle this is through having an app state management solution like [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux).

Explanation: The app state takes care of the data which you are editing. the EditPage just tells the store(App-State container) to edit that data and the framework takes care of the data that should be updated in the PageView.

as a temporary solution you can use an async call to `Navigation.push()` and refresh the PageView State once the EditPage comes back. you can also use an overloaded version of `pop()` to return a success condition which aids for a conditional `setState()`.

Comment: But won't that leave me with the same problem where the new refreshed PageView starts with the first page in the current index rather than the page which was edited?

Comment: Any chance you could steer me toward info or a tutorial on how to use Bloc to update a single PageView?

Comment: I found this [redux tutorial](https://brainsandbeards.com/blog/ultimate-redux-guide-for-flutter). Bloc is used in applications where there are a lot of state changes like a stock market app that refreshes the stock graph every second. if you really wish to use it then, learn from creator  - [bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that `Navigator.pushReplacement(...)` returns a `Future<T>` which completes when you finally return to original context ?
So how are you going to utilize this fact ?
Lets say you want to update a `String` of the original page :

```
String itWillBeUpdated="old value";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext ctx)
{
.
.
.
onPressesed:() async {

itWillBeUpdated= await Navigator.pushReplacement(context,new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (BuildContext context) => EditPage()),);

setState((){});
 
},

}
```

On your editing page , you can define `Navigator.pop(...)` like this :

```
Navigator.pop<String>(context, "new string");
```

by doing this , you can provide any data back to the original page and by calling `setState((){})` , your page will reflect the changes

Comment: I agree with @Sushanth Kille that this is sort of temproary solution and will work fine for simple apps. For more complex apps you should consider using some state management library technics like provider , bloc ,redux etc.

Comment: I can't seem to call "setState". I'm guessing it's because the onPressed function is within the createViewItem of the PageViewer.

Comment: You need a StatefulWidget class to have  setState((){})

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but works somewhat. First I created a `provider` class and added the following;

```
class AudioWidgetProvider with ChangeNotifier {

int refreshIndex;

 setRefreshIndex (ri) {
    refreshIndex = ri;
    return refreshIndex;
  }
}
```

Then in my `PageView Builder` on the first page, I did this;

```
Widget build(context) {
    var audioWidgetProvider = Provider.of<AudioWidgetProvider>(context);
    return
      PreloadPageView.builder(
      controller: PreloadPageController(initialPage: audioWidgetProvider.refreshIndex?? 0),
```

Then to get to the EditPage (2nd screen) I did this;

```
onPressed: () async {
                                                
 audioWidgetProvider.setRefreshIndex(currentIndex);

 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => EditPage()),); }
```

And finally I did this to return to a reloaded PageView scrolled to the edited page;

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>HomePage()));
```

The only problem now is that the PageView list comes from a PHP/Mysql query and I'm not sure what to do if new items are added to the list from the Mysql database. This means the currentIndex will be wrong. But I guess that's the topic of another question.